# Subtract two session storage figures values and play the figure back by document.getE an id and using inner html. to hopefully show the final figure

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I am new to session storage and I am trying to take two stored values and substract them then play it back in innerhtml. I don't know how to do that.

> (index):897 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

```
let propertyPrice = document.getElementById("propertyPrice"); 


if (sessionStorage.getItem("propertyPriceStored")) {

  propertyPrice.value = sessionStorage.getItem("propertyPriceStored");
}

propertyPrice.addEventListener("change", function() {

  sessionStorage.setItem("propertyPriceStored", propertyPrice.value);
});


let deposit = document.getElementById("deposit"); 


if (sessionStorage.getItem("depositStored")) {

  deposit.value = sessionStorage.getItem("depositStored");
}

deposit.addEventListener("change", function() {

  sessionStorage.setItem("depositStored", deposit.value);
});

let loanAmount = propertyPrice - deposit;
loanAmount.document.getElementById("loanAmountResult").innerHTML;
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have there? Do you get any errors? Does the result differ from what you expect, and if so, how?

Comment: I get (index):891 Uncaught ReferenceError: loanAmount is not defined

<p class="medium-headline-serif">£<span id="loanAmountResult">0</span></p>

Comment: I noticed loanAmount was spelt wrong but I get this error. (index):897 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of undefined

Comment: I have tried consolelog after subtracting the variables but is says it is not a number NaN

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the console log to show numbers on reloading of the page but i can get it to happen then and there on the page.

```
   let deposit = document.getElementById("deposit"); 
// See if we have an autosave value
// (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("depositStored")) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  deposit.value = sessionStorage.getItem("depositStored");
}
// Listen for changes in the text field
deposit.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // And save the results into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("depositStored", deposit.value);
});

let loanAmount = propertyPrice.value - deposit.value;

 console.log(loanAmount)

loanAmount.addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("loanAmountResult").innerHTML;
});
```